# Ruby on Rails 3 routing error

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

Am working my way thru Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example 
and am on this page:

http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

Am getting problems when I create an HTML page in the public directory 
which is called public/hello.html and should appear as in Figure 3.3. 
My problem is that when I try to create the page and make it appear at 
http://localhost:3000/hello.html I don't see the rendered page. 
Instead, I get an error which says "Routing error No route matches "/ 
hello.html"

I have not made any changes to the routing; I thought that Rails was 
supposed to be smart enough to find "hello.html" because it's in the 
same directory as the "public/index.html" page and the name of the 
page is "hello.html"?

Can you please explain?

Answer (score 4):

I am doing the same tutorial and had the exact same problem.  I assume this is too late for you but my problem was that I was running rails server from a prior example directory and not the latest directory.  Once I restarted from the sample-app directory, everything work as it should.